# Android elevation property not working

Tags: android, android-layout

Since upgrading to SDK 21 I've been trying to use the elevation property but it never seems to work.

I want to elevate a frame above others so I'm setting the following

```
android:elevation="4dp"
```

but there's no sign of shadow. I've tried buttons and framelayouts but not got any elevation

So here's the full tag

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/panel_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    >
```

Am I missing something else I need to add

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Make sure that the background for the container holding the FrameLayout is not transparent.

Comment: this is probably 90% of elevation not showing issues on views, without specifying background the elevation and translationZ properties  are ignored.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it fixes most of these issues. You should also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/26581346

Comment: android:elevation
android:translationZ on the item to elevate and clipToPadding on the parent will help

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Elevation) Z = Elevation + TranslationZ

so try this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/panel_card"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:elevation="4dp"
  android:translationZ="4dp">
```

Comment: android:translationZ should only be used for animations. Height = elevation (static value) + translationZ(animated value)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a background to it something like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/panel_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background">
```

Instead of using white color. Otherwise the shadows won't work. Also, is it not necessary to use android:translationZ attribute since that just adds to the elevation, but is not required if you don't want animation.