# CardView not showing Shadow in Android L

Tags: android, android-listview, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-cardview

My Cardview inside Listview is not showing shadow in Android L(Nexus 5). Also the round edges are not properly shown. Here is the code for Listview's Adapter View :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myapp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPicture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ivPicture"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And the ListView xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myapp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/app_bg" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBarMain"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone" /></RelativeLayout>
```

It works fine on pre-L devices with proper shadow and rounded corners. But not working aon Android L device. Can you tell what i am missing here?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572048/elevation-on-android-lollipop-not-working

Comment: @AIL But i am not using any transparent background for cardview or any of its parent views

Comment: @isumit Yep, same problem here.

Comment: @greywolf82 in case you have not found a solution yet. I added margin to cardview and its now displaying shadow in Lollipop

Answer (score 311, accepted):

After going through the docs again, I finally found the solution.

Just add `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` to your `CardView` and shadows will appear on Lollipop devices.

What happens is, the content area in a `CardView` take different sizes on pre-lollipop and lollipop devices. So in lollipop devices the shadow is actually covered by the card so its not visible. By adding this attribute the content area remains the same across all devices and the shadow becomes visible.

My xml code is like :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/media_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >
...
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: @alex-lockwood Can you please explain your change i.e, `card_view:cardElevation="2sp"` to `card_view:cardElevation="2dp"` ?

Comment: @Ramswaroop `sp` should only be used for text sizes. `dp` should be used for all other dimensions.

Comment: I my case card_view:cardUseCompatPadding was needed. Additionally I need to change targetSdkVersion to 21. Changing margin has no effect.

Comment: @KishanSolanki124 I think the OP (@isumit) has lost track of this thread.

Comment: app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"... Most important. Add a background color!

Answer (score 61):

Do not forget that to draw shadow you must use `hardwareAccelerated` drawing

`hardwareAccelerated = true`

[image]

`hardwareAccelerated = false`

[image: hardwareAccelerated CardView]

See [Android Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) for details

Comment: Hardware acceleration is enabled by default if your Target API level is >=14 !

Comment: It's working,. But I don't understand reason behind this

Answer (score 60):

use  **`app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`** inside your cardview.
For Example

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/cardviewMarginRight"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/menudetailsbgcolor"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardCornerRadius"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:elevation="0dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 29):

check **hardwareAccelerated**  in manifest make it true , making it false removes shadows , when false shadow appears in xml preview but not in phone .

Answer (score 28):

Add this line to CardView....

```
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" //for enable shadow
card_view:cardElevation="9dp" // this for how much shadow you want to show
```

*Tips*

You can avoid layout_marginTop and layout_marginBottom as shadow itself takes some space to the up and down of it.The amount space defined by how much you will use in card_view:cardElevation="ndp" .

Happy Coding (:

Comment: Or `app:cardElevation`.

Answer (score 22):

Finally i was able to get shadows on Lollipop device by adding margin to the cardview. Here is the final cardview layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myapp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPicture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDetail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivPicture"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I already had the card_view:cardUseCompatPadding values set, still was not able to get the shaddows. What i was missing is this, the margins. And it really worked. Thanks.

Comment: what's your margin value? is `8dp` enough?

Answer (score 13):

You can add this line of code for shadow in card view

```
card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
```

Below you have an example

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, the key was card_view:cardElevation and not android:cardElevation

Answer (score 13):

Simply add this tags:

```
app:cardElevation="2dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

So its become:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="?colorPrimary"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:contentPadding="1dp" />
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try by adding this line

```
 card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

The Whole code will seems like this

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case the shadow was not showing on Android L devices because I did not add a margin. The problem is that the CardView creates this margin automatically on <5 devices so now I do it like this:

```
CardView card = new CardView(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
if (Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP == Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
    params.setMargins(shadowSize, shadowSize, shadowSize,
            shadowSize);
} else {
    card.setMaxCardElevation(shadowSize);
}
card.setCardElevation(shadowSize);
card.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: adding margins to cardview from layout file works. Didn't tried from code

Answer (score 7):

Add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in your manifests file like below it works for me

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.MyCardViewActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"></activity>
```

Answer (score 5):

In case if you're looking for **MaterialCardView** shadow (elevation), then add this line of code in the XML and it will show the proper elevation-

```
app:cardElevation="24dp"
app:cardMaxElevation="36dp"
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all make sure that following dependencies are proper added and compiled in build.gradle file

```
    dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'

    }
```

and after this try the following code :

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

problem rises in Android L beacuse layout_margin attribute is not added

Answer (score 0):

My recyclerview was slow in loading so by reading the stackoverflow.com I changed hardwareAccelerated to "false" then the elevation is not showing in the device. The I changed back to true. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Card view can't show shadow because of your `RelativeLayout` is on the card view's shadow. To show the shadow add margins on your Card view. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you check your manifest first if you wrote `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` 
you should make it `true` to having shadow for the card
Like this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35962665/5416148)

Answer (score 0):

Check you're not using `android:layerType="software"` in your **RecyclerView**.

Changing it to `android:layerType="hardware"` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also test by assigning:

android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

in manifest file under application tag.

As sometimes some custom views are not supported assigning value to above statement "true" or "false" can be a solution.
[For more Information refer to android studio docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel)

Answer (score 0):

If you use MaterialCardView the option to go is 'app:cardElevation="8dp'
the "8dp" is a referential size

Answer (score 0):

Insert `MaterialCardView` into `FrameLayout`. Add margins for shadow. Add `app:cardElevation`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">
```

Answer (score -1):

move your "uses-sdk" attribute in top of the manifest like the below answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658827/1394139

Comment: This sounds radical