# How can I group items from a cardview?

Tags: android, android-cardview

Is there a way that I can group items from a cardview by day like image below?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best practice to group items into CardView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273203/what-is-the-best-practice-to-group-items-into-cardview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expandable list view and customize the style and have it always expanded. Another way you can do it is to sort your items based on certain criteria (ie. the date) then pad your data set with null/dummy data with certain descriptions which can be programmed to render different views.

[Here's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) the documentation for expandable list view