# Multiple RecyclerView in one Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

i have a fragment with following design 
need help to implement this.

[image: MainFragment]

tried to put it as Header in adapter but no luck.

**My Adapter**

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements GetJSONListener {
private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;
private final int VIEW_TYPE_HEADER = 2;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
private Context mContext;
private CallWSTask callWSTask;
private View VaultsHeader;
private ArrayList<String> userVaults;
private MyVaultsAdapter vaultsAdapter;
private List<VaultsPojo> vaultsPojo;


// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public FeedListAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItems, View header) {
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
    mContext = context;
    if(!header.equals(null)){
        this.VaultsHeader = header;
    }



}
public boolean isHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_note, null);


    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.feed_note, parent, false);
        return new FeedListViewHolder(view);

    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_item, parent, false);
        return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
    }else if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_HEADER){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.vaults_header_view, parent, false);
        return new HeaderViewHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof FeedListViewHolder) {
        final FeedItem feedItem = feedItems.get(position);
        FeedListViewHolder feedListViewHolder = (FeedListViewHolder) holder;

        feedListViewHolder.display_name_tv.setText(feedItem.getUserDisp().getFirstName() + " " + feedItem.getUserDisp().getLastName());
        feedListViewHolder.display_name_tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, UserProfileActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("userid", feedItem.getUserId());
                mContext.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(feedItem.getCreateDate()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        feedListViewHolder.timestamp_tv.setText(timeAgo);
        feedListViewHolder.abbreviationtxt.setText("Ma");
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mContext.getString(R.string.ENVIRONMENT1) + feedItem.getUserDisp().getProfilepicName())
                .into(feedListViewHolder.user_iv);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(SharedPreferenceUtils.getProfilePic(mContext)).into(((FeedListViewHolder) holder).comment_user_iv);

        feedListViewHolder.like_count.setText(feedItem.getFavoriteCount() + "");
        feedListViewHolder.comment_count.setText(feedItem.getCommentCount() + "");
        feedListViewHolder.share_count.setText(feedItem.getShareCount() + "");

        if (feedItem.isLike()) {
            feedListViewHolder.like_empty_iv.setImageDrawable(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_helpful_selected));
        } else {
            feedListViewHolder.like_empty_iv.setImageDrawable(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_helpful));
        }


        feedListViewHolder.like_empty_iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Liked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        feedListViewHolder.comment_iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "coment!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        feedListViewHolder.share_iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "shared!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        if (feedItem.getFeedType().equals("Note")) {
            feedListViewHolder.FeedNote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedListViewHolder.FeedAskQuestion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedListViewHolder.FedMcq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedListViewHolder.FeedEmbedYouTube.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedListViewHolder.FeedEmbedWeb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedListViewHolder.embed_disp_tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getNotedisp().getNoteContent()));

            if (feedItem.getNotedisp().getAttachment().toString() != "[]") {

                if (feedItem.getNoteDisp().getAttachment().size() == 1) {
                    if (feedItem.getNoteDisp().getAttachment().get(0).isImage()) {
                        feedListViewHolder.note_post_iv01.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        feedListViewHolder.gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Picasso.with(mContext)
                                .load(mContext.getString(R.string.ENVIRONMENT1) + "/MediaImages/Medium/" + feedItem.getNoteDisp().getAttachment().get(0).getFileName())
                                .into(feedListViewHolder.note_post_iv01);

                        Log.v("one image",mContext.getString(R.string.ENVIRONMENT1) + "/MediaImages/Medium/" + feedItem.getNoteDisp().getAttachment().get(0).getFileName());

                    } else if (feedItem.getNoteDisp().getAttachment().get(0).isVideo()) {

                    }

                }else if(feedItem.getNoteDisp().getAttachment().size() > 1){
                    feedListViewHolder.gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    feedListViewHolder.note_post_iv01.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    FeedNoteAttachmentAdapter attachmentAdapter = new FeedNoteAttachmentAdapter(mContext, feedItem.getNoteDisp().getAttachment());
                    feedListViewHolder.gridView.setAdapter(attachmentAdapter);
                    feedListViewHolder.gridView.autoresize();

                }


            }else{
                feedListViewHolder.gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.note_post_iv01.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else if (feedItem.getFeedType().equals("Embed")) {


            if (feedItem.getEmbed().getEmbedType().equals("youtube")) {
                feedListViewHolder.FeedNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.FeedAskQuestion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.FedMcq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.FeedEmbedWeb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.FeedEmbedYouTube.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                feedListViewHolder.btnplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((FeedListViewHolder) holder).youtube_title.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getEmbed().getEmbedTitle()));
                ((FeedListViewHolder) holder).youtube_disp.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getEmbed().getEmbedDescription()));
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getEmbed().getEmbedImageUrl())
                        .into(feedListViewHolder.youtube_post_iv);

            } else {
                feedListViewHolder.FeedNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.FeedAskQuestion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.FedMcq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.FeedEmbedYouTube.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.FeedEmbedWeb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((FeedListViewHolder) holder).embed_title.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getEmbed().getEmbedTitle()));
                ((FeedListViewHolder) holder).embed_disp.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getEmbed().getEmbedDescription()));

                if ((feedItem.getEmbed().getEmbedImageUrl() != null) && (feedItem.getEmbed().getEmbedImageUrl().length() > 0) && (!feedItem.getEmbed().getEmbedImageUrl().equals("null"))) {
                    feedListViewHolder.embed_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getEmbed().getEmbedImageUrl())
                            .into(feedListViewHolder.embed_image);
                } else {
                    feedListViewHolder.embed_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            } //youTubeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        } else if (feedItem.getFeedType().equals("AskQuestion")) {
            feedListViewHolder.FeedNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedListViewHolder.FeedAskQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedListViewHolder.FedMcq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedListViewHolder.FeedEmbedYouTube.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedListViewHolder.FeedEmbedWeb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedListViewHolder.question_txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getAskQuestions().getQuestionText()));
        } else if (feedItem.getFeedType().equals("MCQ")) {
            feedListViewHolder.FeedNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedListViewHolder.FeedAskQuestion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedListViewHolder.FedMcq.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedListViewHolder.FeedEmbedYouTube.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedListViewHolder.FeedEmbedWeb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedListViewHolder.mcq_question.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getMCQ().getQuestion()));

            Typeface ubantulight = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/Ubuntu-L.ttf");
            feedListViewHolder.radioButton01.setTypeface(ubantulight);
            feedListViewHolder.radioButton02.setTypeface(ubantulight);
            feedListViewHolder.radioButton03.setTypeface(ubantulight);
            feedListViewHolder.radioButton04.setTypeface(ubantulight);


            if (feedItem.getMCQ().getAnswer().size() == 4) {
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton01.setText(feedItems.get(position).getMCQ().getAnswer().get(0).getAnswerText());
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton02.setText(feedItems.get(position).getMCQ().getAnswer().get(1).getAnswerText());
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton03.setText(feedItems.get(position).getMCQ().getAnswer().get(2).getAnswerText());
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton04.setText(feedItems.get(position).getMCQ().getAnswer().get(3).getAnswerText());
                // viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            } else if (feedItem.getMCQ().getAnswer().size() == 3) {
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton04.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton03.setText(feedItems.get(position).getMCQ().getAnswer().get(2).getAnswerText());
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton01.setText(feedItems.get(position).getMCQ().getAnswer().get(0).getAnswerText());
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton02.setText(feedItems.get(position).getMCQ().getAnswer().get(1).getAnswerText());
                // viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            } else if (feedItem.getMCQ().getAnswer().size() == 2) {
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton01.setText(feedItems.get(position).getMCQ().getAnswer().get(0).getAnswerText());
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton02.setText(feedItems.get(position).getMCQ().getAnswer().get(1).getAnswerText());
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton03.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton04.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            } else {
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton01.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton02.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton03.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedListViewHolder.radioButton04.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

        }

        //this line is important
        feedListViewHolder.itemView.setTag(feedItems.get(position));
        //setAnimation(feedListViewHolder.mainlinear_feed,position);
    } else if (holder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
        LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;

        if (!Utilities.Isconnetcted(mContext) && position >= 30) {
            loadingViewHolder.errormsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }else if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder){
        HeaderViewHolder headerViewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;


        userVaults = SharedPreferenceUtils.getUserVaults(mContext);

        //String vaultsjsonstring = new Gson().toJson(userVaults);
        vaultsPojo = ResponseParser.parsevaultsJson(userVaults.toString());

        vaultsAdapter = new MyVaultsAdapter(mContext,vaultsPojo);
        headerViewHolder.vaultsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext,2));
        headerViewHolder.vaultsRecyclerView.setAdapter(vaultsAdapter);

    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return feedItems == null ? 0 : feedItems.size();
}

@Override
public void onRemoteCallComplete(String jsonFromWSCall) {

}

public void addFeedItem(List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
    //this.feedItems.add(position,feedItems);

    this.feedItems.addAll(feedItems);
    //notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public String getLastFeedId() {
    if (!this.feedItems.isEmpty()) {
        return this.feedItems.get(this.feedItems.size() - 2).getFeedId();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(isHeader(position)){
        return VIEW_TYPE_HEADER;
    }else {
        return feedItems.get(position) == null ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }

}


static class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ProgressBar progressBar;
    public TextView errormsg;

    public LoadingViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        errormsg = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.errormsg);
    }
}
static class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public RecyclerView vaultsRecyclerView;


    public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        vaultsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_Vaults_recycler_view);

    }
}}
```

Tried library
 [RvJoiner](https://github.com/j2esu/rv-joiner)

I tried to implement two recycler views one below the other in the same xml but only one showed up and the other didnt. It would be great if you could link me up to some tutorials.

Comment: Please post your code and what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: If you want a single scrolling for both parts together you can just use a single RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. Please write more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of merging two `RecyclerView` into one, you can just define one `RecyclerView` (so one adapter) with two different view types and *play* with `GridLayoutManager`, so that elements could fill a different number of columns depending on their type.

[Here](https://github.com/thetonrifles/android-recycler-grid) on GitHub I have an implementation that does exactly what you are trying to do.

I provide you below just few details about code and main things to highlight:

- Define in your model two different item types, one for Grid part and another one for List part. They should both extend the same abstract class. Of course you can add all parameters you need for rendering your items. In this simple case I'm just using a label in each element.

  ```
  public abstract class AbstractItem {

      public static final int GRID_TYPE = 0;
      public static final int LIST_TYPE = 1;

      private String label;

      public AbstractItem(String label) {
          this.label = label;
      }

      // getters and setters here

      abstract public int getType();

  }

  public class GridItem extends AbstractItem {

      public GridItem(String label) {
          super(label);
      }

      @Override
      public int getType() {
          return GRID_TYPE;
      }

  }

  public class ListItem extends AbstractItem {

      public ListItem(String label) {
          super(label);
      }

      @Override
      public int getType() {
          return LIST_TYPE;
      }

  }
  ```
- In your `Activity`, initialize `RecyclerView` by using a `GridLayoutManager` implementing behavior you need. In particular, your grid will have 2 columns. `GridItem` elements will take one column only, while `ListItem` elements will take 2 columns (so they will use a colspan equals to 2). You can get this result by using method `setSpanSizeLookup` as follows:

  ```
  GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
  manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
      @Override
      public int getSpanSize(int position) {
          AbstractItem item = mItems.get(position);
          switch (item.getType()) {
              case AbstractItem.GRID_TYPE:
                  // grid items to take 1 column
                  return 1;
              default:
                  // list items to take 2 columns
                  return 2;
          }
      }
  });
  ```

This is the final outcome I get:

[image]

Hope this could help.

Comment: @RonakMakwana Glad I could help! :)

Comment: My GridItem has Following items  private String Text;
    private int NewPostCount;
    private String abbreviation;
    private String Color;
    private String FooterColor;
    private long TotalPost;
    private int UnAnswered;
    public boolean selected; my List item is collection of arraylist. so how can i make AbstractItem to combine both items in one.

Comment: @RonakMakwana you don't need to share all data among different view types. Just common attributes can be put in AbstractItem. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936863/android-how-do-i-switch-layouts-for-a-recyclerview-list/34941058#34941058) is an answer where I explained how to proceed, by wrapping your model object inside class used for representing list item.

Comment: i tried your code. its working fine with my all views. but i am getting **android.support.v7.widget.recyclerview$viewholder.mitemviewtype' on a null object reference**  while adding more data to adapter. can you please help?

Comment: @RonakMakwana could you share [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/) code of your adapter, so that I can better understand what's going on?

Comment: @RonakMakwana can I ask you which is the row generating crash?

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/L5iFR8DZLNvUJ387sSeuuq this is my logcat. the error occurs when i am adding new data to adapter.

Comment: @RonakMakwana at high level, I don't see relevant errors. Just I think you can remove line 245 in your adapter. Maybe there's something wrong in how you are filling and updating your RecyclerView from your fragment. Is it possible for you to share that code too?

Comment: There is a method to additemfeed in adapter I just call it in my fragment by passing data. (Data which has only one viewtype list_viewtype)

Comment: @RonakMakwana uhm... looking at code it seems you have 3 view types, having 3 corresponding view holder: MyVaultViewHolder, LoadingViewHolder and FeedListViewHolder. Since you have just a method for adding FeedItems I'm wondering is how you add items for classes VaultsPojo and LoadingItem for example.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/BDcv6XaKsuSWmYqUNbSDyz here is the Updated  Fragment Where i am trying to add data to Adapter Thanks

Comment: @RonakMakwana line 54... `newadapter.notifyItemInserted(mItems.size() + 1)`... after you insert item, `mItems` size changed and correct position is `mItems.size()-1`.

Comment: no luck.. do you need any more info? changed the position and notified adapter. but still having same issue

Comment: @thetonrifles is it possible to add a title separating the grid from the list?

Comment: @EduardoBonfa Yes sure. In the example there are just 2 view types but you can add other types. A header is basically another view type that will fill the entire width of the recycler view (like the list item) but will be rendered in a different way (using another layout and another binding logic in the adapter).