# Airbnb Epoxy For Gmail like Dashboard interface

Tags: android, epoxy, epoxy-modelview

am building an app which displays a list of objects .Am using android recycler view for now.

Now as per new requirements , I want to display this list in groups , similar to as described in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848401/divide-elements-on-groups-in-recyclerview)

My Question is :

1. Can I implement it using [Airbnb Epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy)?
2. Will epoxy be an overkill ?
3. Or should I just go with the solution provided in the SO question?

Please advice.
Thanks !

Comment: I don't know all details of Epoxy but I see it requires annotation processing and also to add dependencies like ButterKnife. Also, it seems ideal for complex layouts where you also don't know if the item will be displayed or not (it depends on model). If you just want to display a list of objects in groups you can maybe start by just implementing your adapter so that it handles different view types, like in the SO question you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @thetonrifles . Am trying with your approach !