# How to add elevation on android api < 21

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having some trouble adding elevation for android version < 21. Recently I found it easy to add elevation on card view but I could not achieve the same result for other views like picture view, toolbar, drawer layout, etc. Can anyone help me with it???

For example: if I want to add elevation to my drawer layout as per the material design, what should I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_64dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android studio" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add your xml file here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One work around is that  you can put all these view inside **CardView**

**Just put `LinearLayout`  inside `CardView`**

> For example :-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ....
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">


 <!--  other view that you want to elevate -->
 <DrawerLayout ../>  or <Toolbar  ---->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can I do it for Drawer layout and tool bar as well??

Comment: yes you can do that  :) its child class of `FrameLayout` so its container layout

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems like this will work. But what if I want the shadow to appear at only one side? Like to the right for drawer and downward for toolbar???

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599603/cardview-not-showing-shadow-in-android-l this may help you