# Cardview shadow for ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-cardview

[image]

(1 screenshot - ImageView visibility is visible, 2 screenshot - gone)

When using `ImageView` with `CardView` we can say that shadow isn't visible at all (especially on the smartphone display)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/ImageViewWrapper"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@color/black_1000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_folder"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

`android:elevation` doesn't make any effect (0dp, 5dp, or 20dp - nothing changes), so I just set it 0dp

Can we control this cardview shadow, make it stronger/bigger/thicker?

3 screenshot - here MX Player app example of video thumbnail ImageView (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad)

[image]

**Update**

I set  `app:cardElevation="7dp"`
and `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`
No progress... and `cardUseCompatPadding` made my image height size smaller and now I have black bars at left/right

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599603/cardview-not-showing-shadow-in-android-l/33044134

Comment: @duggu I have shadow, it's different problem

Comment: Why are you using `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImagefView` ?? Is there any reason?

Comment: @Xenolion `ImageView` usually is always `AppCompatImageView`, but in some cases we have to explicitly set `AppCompatImageView` if, for example, using custom list item xml for RecyclerView and inflating like `View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);`

Comment: @Xenolion *AppCompatImageView will automatically be used when you use ImageView in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.* https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html

Comment: I have got it, thank you I have understood. But I think your image is on top of the card view. Try adding some padding in the cardview as a test?

Comment: @Xenolion I just think CardView shadow is weak and visibility is good only if CardView's content not that filled and colored (like mine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `app:cardElevation="4dp"`instead of `android:elevation`.

Also add this `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`.

UPDATE

Also consider changing the CardView size to:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: updated question using `app:cardElevation="7dp" app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`, no progress, and cardUseCompatPadding ruins image size

Comment: I have updated the answer! Also use `ImageView` instead of `AppCompatImageView`. and set adjustLayoutBounds to it.

Comment: ImageView == AppCompatImageView

Comment: I use layout constraints and I set specific size for my views, I can't use wrap_content...

Comment: changing value of `app:cardElevation` actually makes shadow bigger but it's so weak/transparent that we don't really see it very good.. As I understand we can't control shadow's transparent and color for CardView

Comment: But I dont think you have any grey layouts/view there!

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: The shadow in `CardView` is just an illusion of grey colour thats when added looks like a shadow since it has a gradient. Infact you can make your own shadow without `CardView`!

Comment: It didn't help me at all

Answer (score 1):

Make sure enable hardware Acceleration

You can do it at application level:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

Or activity level:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
    <activity ... />
    <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
</application>
```

Or Window level, view level, etc.

Comment: I believe it's enabled by default, anyway I tried to add `<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>` but it didn't change anything, also I guess if it was disabled then shadow would not be visible at all

Comment: @user924 What is your minimum targeted android version?

Comment: Android 4.1 (API level 16)