# No elevation or corner radius displayed for CardView that is inside a CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

I think this might be a bug, but will ask just here just in case...

I am using the [Cheesesquare demo](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) (synced to latest version this morning), I don't see elevation or radius for a CardView.

I think I can add the following attributes to the CardView, but it doesn't work:

```
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
```

(edit) - also added no transparency color, as per this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572048/elevation-on-android-lollipop-not-working/30969174#30969174):

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
```

The complete CardView (for the "Info" card). I have tried (lines 73-99 of activity_detail.xml):

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Info"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Is there anything else I need to do?  I think this should display - but it is not - on any device.

[image: See image])

Comment: in which IDE you are testing your layout?

Comment: The app is being deployed to devices, I really think it doesn't matter.  I use Android Studio for development.

Comment: Are you using lollipop device to test the application?

Comment: I have tested on both Lollipop, and non-Lollipop devices (Samsung S3, S4, and MotoX - 2nd gen);  The elevation doesn't show on any device.

Comment: just try giving:   android:elevation="5dp" inside your cardview tag, it might help.