# Android – MapFragment overlay button shadow, just like MyLocation button

Tags: java, android, material-design, mapfragment, mylocationoverlay

I'm struggling to add a shadow to my custom overlay button over the google map. My goal is to make my custom button look just like Google's MyLocation  button. Here's how my app looks like now:

[image]

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    style="@style/AppTheme">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/icon_gray"
        android:onClick="searchButtonClicked"
        android:background="@drawable/mapbutton"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch.SearchBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searchbox"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

mapbutton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="1.3dp" />
            <solid android:color="#55FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="1.3dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ccb3b3b3" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="1.3dp" />
            <solid android:color="#A9FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="1.3dp" />
            <solid android:color="#baffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I have already tried changing the android:elevation value on the ImageButton. Unfortunately, adding elevation value doesn't seem to add a shadow to the button. Is there a way to add a shadow to my mapbutton drawable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
                    <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="2dp" android:right="2dp">
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#DC5F0A" android:startColor="#E68F54"/>
                    <!--
                     <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA" /> 
                    -->
                    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I hope it will.

Comment: The shadow doesn't really look like the one on Google's button. The shadow needs to be softer.

Comment: i just given a solution.. u want to change color,padding and radius as u need.......... if answer is useful upvote it

Comment: I understand that. But my point is that the shadow of the location button is  not a solid color, well, it's a shadow – and I have no idea how to achieve that effect.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572048/elevation-on-android-lollipop-not-working) what worked for me was:

```
<ImageButton
  android:clipToPadding="false"
  android:outlineProvider="bounds"
  android:elevation="2dp" />
```