# TextView Is Hidden When Adding "Elevation" to View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, view

I've a textview and a view, I Want to show the textview above the view, It's working well, But **when adding elevation to the View, the TextView is hidden under that view** .

XML :

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:id="@+id/view" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/view" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Framelayout for this purpose, You have to remove `android:background="#ffffffff"` because of that you were not getting your elevation and it was hiding textview

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:scaleType="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="18dp" />
```

Check [elevation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26581346/2826147)