# Android : Elevation for toggle button with custom Background

Tags: android, android-layout, togglebutton, android-elevation

I want to use custom toggle buttons. Currently I use the following xml file to define a "custom" background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switchon" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switchoff" android:state_checked="false"/>
 </selector>
```

with

and

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#FF0000" />
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="35dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="35dp"
    android:topRightRadius="35dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="35dp"/>
</shape>
```

as background.

When I include the button in the layout with the following code, it produces a red/green toggle button.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/ToggleButton1"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_button"
    android:text=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:layout_marginStart="99dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/section_label"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Toggle"
    android:checked="true" />
```

Now i want this button to have a certain elevation. Adding android:elevation="2dp" does not produce any effect.

Can anyone tell me how to do that? I was not able to find a solution to that.

Comment: It may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572048/elevation-on-android-lollipop-not-working

Comment: Hey, I'm not using transparent colors & up to now none of the other solutions worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue I put a CardView beneath the Toggle button. Setting an elevation did work right away with the card view.

Thanks for the input! :-)

Comment: What do you mean you put a CardView underneath? Can you provide the code for this please? I have a ToggleButton with a custom background (round) as well, and it actually does form little shadows to the left and right but nothing below!?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Use SwitchCompat instead of Toggle button

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/Switch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff=""
        android:text="Toggle Switch"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textOn=""
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:padding="20dp"/>
```

This will definatly works

Comment: Hey, I use a "custom" background that changes the color when the button toggles.

Comment: @Chuchaki check out my edited answer i hope it will work

Comment: you can directly use elevation in  SwitchCompat

Comment: Hey! I basically just need a red circel that turns gree if clicked. The Switch Compat has a slider. If I apply a solid background, it still does not show a shadow. Thanks for the input though!